# dreamweaver regex replace css rule

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have some css file, but in some day, i make a mistake, replace all the `space` to `empty`, so it cause some rules are broken.

```
Wrong way                right way
#body.content{...}       #body .content{...}

#content#title{...}      #content #title{...}
```

I tried `[a-z]#` => `$1 #`, it become `#conten$1 #title{...}`. How to do the correct regex in dreamweaver? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `([a-zA-Z0-9])([#.])` and replace by `$1 $2`. Don't forget to check "Use regular expression" in the search box.

**Explanation:**

- `(` : start matching group 1

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` : match letters lower and uppercase and digits
- `)` : end matching group 1
- `(` : start matching group 2

  - `[#.]` : match either `#` or `.`
- `)` : end matching group 2